# driver.quit() does not close browser windows

Tags: selenium, automation, selenium-webdriver

I have a framework wherein I am running my tests; any errors cause the WebDriver instance to call something like a handleexception method where I call the driver.quit() method.  I feel that driver.quit() attempts to close the browser but then the browser throws a dialog box with message do you want to leave this page - which is not taken care of.  There is no exception thrown, but remaining test cases do not work as they launch browser but throw a modal dialog present exception which is understandable.
How can I work around this?

**handleexception method :**

```
    Driver.getFailedTestCaseNames().add(this.getTestcaseName());
    String failedStepStr = "";
    failedStepStr = "Test Case failed while executing step " + stepNo + " - Method Name:" + t.getMethodnm() + ", Field Name:" + t.getField() + " , Field value:" + t.getValue();        

    LOG.error("Test Case Name: " + testcaseName + " failed while executing step " + stepNo + " - Method Name:" + t.getMethodnm() + ", Field Name:" + t.getField() + " , Field value:"
            + t.getValue() + ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(th));

    CaptureScreenshot objCapturScreenshot = new CaptureScreenshot();

    objCapturScreenshot.caputureImage(testcaseName);
    System.out.println(" in handle exception");
    driver.quit();

    System.out.println("Test case failed : "+this.getTestcaseName());
    throw new TestAutomationException(failedStepStr, th);
```

**the log for guilty test case is :**

```
    org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.
    Build info: version: '2.35.0', revision: 'c916b9d', time: '2013-08-12 15:42:01'
    System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_11'
    Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:548)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:569)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.quit(RemoteWebDriver.java:423)
        at com.bmc.core.test.domain.TestCase.handleException(TestCase.java:364)
        at com.bmc.core.test.domain.TestCase.execute(TestCase.java:136)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor40.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:702)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:894)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1219)
        at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
        at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:768)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:87)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1185)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1110)
        at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1022)
        at org.testng.TestNG.privateMain(TestNG.java:1325)
        at org.testng.TestNG.main(TestNG.java:1294)
    Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    Build info: version: '2.35.0', revision: 'c916b9d', time: '2013-08-12 15:42:01'
    System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_11'
    Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:75)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:527)
        ... 26 more
    Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:166)
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.SocketInputBuffer.fillBuffer(SocketInputBuffer.java:90)
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.readLine(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:281)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:92)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:62)
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:254)
        at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:289)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:252)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractClientConnAdapter.java:219)
        at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:300)
        at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:127)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:712)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:517)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.fallBackExecute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:319)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:298)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:66)
        ... 27 more
```

**the log for subsequent test cases is :**

```
    com.bmc.core.test.exception.TestAutomationException: Test Case failed while executing step 1 - Method Name:waitAndSwitchToWindow,
    Field Name:Inquira Information Manager , Field value:20000
            at com.bmc.core.test.domain.TestCase.handleException(TestCase.java:400)
            at com.bmc.core.test.domain.TestCase.execute(TestCase.java:136)
            at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor40.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
            at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:702)
            at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:894)
            at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1219)
            at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
            at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
            at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:768)
            at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
            at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
            at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
            at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
            at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
            at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
            at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:87)
            at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1185)
            at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1110)
            at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1022)
            at org.testng.TestNG.privateMain(TestNG.java:1325)
            at org.testng.TestNG.main(TestNG.java:1294)
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at com.bmc.core.test.domain.TestCase.execute(TestCase.java:99)
            ... 22 more
    Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.UnhandledAlertException: Modal dialog present: 
    Build info: version: '2.35.0', revision: 'c916b9d', time: '2013-08-12 15:42:01'
    System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_11'
    Session ID: ac1a28e7-2c24-443f-9c0e-d308645fab2d
    Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
    Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, javascriptEnabled=true, elementScrollBehavior=0, ignoreZoomSetting=false, enablePersistentHover=true,
    ie.ensureCleanSession=false, browserName=internet explorer, enableElementCacheCleanup=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=dismiss,
    version=10, ie.usePerProcessProxy=false, ignoreProtectedModeSettings=false, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, requireWindowFocus=false,
    initialBrowserUrl=http://www.localohst:10879/, handlesAlerts=true, ie.forceCreateProcessApi=false, nativeEvents=true, browserAttachTimeout=0,
    ie.browserCommandLineSwitches=, takesScreenshot=true}]
            at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
            at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:191)
            at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createUnhandledAlertException(ErrorHandler.java:172)
            at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:141)
            at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:554)
            at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:569)
            at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.getWindowHandles(RemoteWebDriver.java:432)
            at com.bmc.core.test.app.Base.waitAndSwitchToWindow(Base.java:278)
            ... 27 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after suggestions by paul i came up with this snippet and this works fine.... it closes all browsers on exit whether or not they throw a alert on closing...

```
    try
    {
    Set<String> windowIterator = driver.getWindowHandles();            
    Iterator<String> iter = windowIterator.iterator();
    System.out.println("no of windows to close ="+windowIterator.size());
    LOG.debug("no of windows to close ="+windowIterator.size());
    int i=0;
    while (iter.hasNext()) 
    {   
        try 
        {
            i++;
            System.out.println("lopp value = "+i);
            LOG.debug("loop value = "+i);
            String windowHandle = iter.next();
            driver.switchTo().window(windowHandle);
            String windowTitle = driver.getTitle();
            System.out.println("title="+driver.getTitle()+" - attempting to close this window");
            LOG.debug("title="+driver.getTitle()+" - attempting to close this window");
            driver.close();
            Thread.sleep(5000);

            while(isAlertPresent())
                {
                try 
                {
                    driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
                    System.out.println("alert accepted after close");
                    LOG.debug("alert accepted after close");
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                }
                catch (Exception e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    LOG.debug("alert loop... inner while --> exception : "+e.getMessage());
                }   
                }               
            System.out.println("title="+windowTitle+" - window closed");
            LOG.debug("title="+windowTitle+" - window closed");
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            LOG.debug("window loop... outer while --> exception : "+e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    while(isAlertPresent())
    {
        driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
        System.out.println("alert accepted before quit");
        LOG.debug("alert accepted before quit");
        Thread.sleep(5000); 
    }       
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        LOG.debug("outer exception : "+e.getMessage());
    }

    driver.quit();
    System.out.println("quitting the driver instance");
    LOG.debug("quitting the driver instance");
    //==================================================================================
```

Comment: Hi, could you please share the code of isAlertPresent() method? Thanks

Comment: sorry for not showing it earlier                                             

 public boolean isAlertPresent() 
 { 
     try 
     { 
         Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
   String str = alert.getText();
   System.out.println(str);   
         return true; 
     }   
     catch (NoAlertPresentException Ex) 
     { 
         return false; 
     }   
 }

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

The above code should close the dialog after it appears.

Comment: can we call the instance of driver object after already calling quit() on it? else how do i get hold of the dialog?

Comment: use driver.close() to try to close the browser, then my code then use quit.