# Not able to close instances of different browser using driver.quit

Tags: java, selenium, quit

I have opened different browser instances and at the end i would like to close all the instances but when i use driver.close() or driver.quit() it is only closing the last instance of the browser. Please help.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;


public class showClose {

static WebDriver driver;

public showClose(WebDriver driver){
    this.driver=driver;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    showClose sc = new showClose(driver);
    sc.IE("http://www.msn.com");
    sc.Firefox("http://seleniumhq.org");
    sc.Chrome("http://google.com");

    driver.quit();

}

//Internet Explorer driver
public void IE(String URL){
    //Set the driver property for IE
    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver",                 System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\IEDriverServer.exe");

    DesiredCapabilities ieCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();  
    ieCapabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true);

    //Create object of Internet explorer driver
    driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(ieCapabilities);
    driver.get(URL);
}

//Firefox driver
public void Firefox(String URL){
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get(URL);
}

//Chrome driver
public void Chrome(String URL){
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",      System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\chromedriver.exe");

    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get(URL);

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step1:**

In Main Class declare 'List list' Interface and declare it as 'Static'

```
public static  List<WebDriver> drivers;
```

**Reason for Using List:** It represents an ordered list of objects, meaning you can access the elements of a List in a specific order, and by an index too. You can also add the same element more than once to a List.

**Step2:**
Now Create a Constructor in which we will point to out current driver from the Stored List of Drivers. (*I assume my class name as Test*)

```
public Test()

{
this.drivers = new ArrayList<WebDriver>();
}
```

**Step3:**

Add a WebDriver Instance to out ArrayList for drivers in all methods of IE, Firefox and Chrome.

```
this.drivers.add(driver);
```

**Step4:** In main class copy all the instances of stored drivers to an object and use that object to close all opened instances.

```
for(WebDriver d : drivers)
{
d.quit();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In every call of „sc.IE“, „sc.Firefox“ or „sc.Chrome“ you are overwriting the instance variable “driver”.
So the only driver that is closed by your call “driver.quit” is the last one.
If you want to close the browser after visiting the URL you would either have to do a “driver.quit” in before each call to „sc.IE“, „sc.Firefox“ or „sc.Chrome“ or manage a list of WebDrivers and close all of them.
For example you could do something like this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

public class ShowClose {

private List<WebDriver> drivers;

public ShowClose(){
    this.drivers = new ArrayList<WebDriver>();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ShowClose sc = new ShowClose();
    sc.IE("http://www.msn.com");
    sc.Firefox("http://seleniumhq.org");
    sc.Chrome("http://google.com");

    sc.CloseAll();
}

public void CloseAll() {
    for(WebDriver d : drivers) {
        d.quit();
    }
}

//Internet Explorer driver
public void IE(String URL){
    //Set the driver property for IE
    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\IEDriverServer.exe");

    DesiredCapabilities ieCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();  
    ieCapabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true);

    //Create object of Internet explorer driver
    WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(ieCapabilities);
    driver.get(URL);
    this.drivers.add(driver);
}

//Firefox driver
public void Firefox(String URL){
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get(URL);
    this.drivers.add(driver);
}

//Chrome driver
public void Chrome(String URL){
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\chromedriver.exe");

    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get(URL);
    this.drivers.add(driver);
}
```

}

Answer (score -3):

For one thing: `driver.quit()` should be used if you want to close all windows. `driver.close()` is for a single window.
Perhaps it has something to do with the browser windows throwing an alert when they attempt to close?

[See this other topic on StackOverflow for a solution to that problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20660167/driver-quit-does-not-close-browser-windows)